# Results of Fetching appeared before actual fetch

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

Today i when was backtracking this code

```
  func salesCountForEmployees(_ employee: Employee) -> String {
    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Sale> = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Sale")
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "employee == %@", employee)
    fetchRequest.predicate = predicate

    let context = employee.managedObjectContext!
    do {

        let results = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)

        return "\(results.count)"
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        return "0"
    }
}
```

i was "suprised" because backtrace field showed me that results had been fetched even before actual fetch execution.[image]

then after actual fetch execution results changed (of course) 
[image]

Please maybe someone have any idea why it could be occured?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `results` variable is declared, but not initialized (because fetch hasn't been performed yet), so it points to uncleared field of memory that was previosly used by your app. When you continue program execution, "junk" inside `results` variable gets overwritten by valid fetch results array.

So it does not mean that you've performed fetch request right before command execution.